# scikit-learn: Identification property in clustering dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

While performing a KMeans clustering in scikit-learn, I need to feed the dataset of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. Each sample of the dataset corresponds to a user, identified by a `user_id`, which is not exactly a feature. So, if feed the dataset in this format, I lose the identification info for each sample.

So, how do I store user_ids in the dataset?

Comment: run KMeans and then concatenate user_ids back to the ouput